# ddslick not scrolling options in chrome

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, overflow

I have issues making my ddslick options scroll. The problem is on my larger dropdown list it extends the entire page even past my page layout.

If I add `max-height` to `dd-options` it shrinks it to the desired height but then options cut off.

If I add `overflow:scroll` to the same class in css it now scrolls in Firefox only :(

If I edit the ddslick script and include my max height and overflow scroll to the style there then again the options will not scroll in chrome.

If I use chromes inspection I can see the code missing from the class that ddslick has generated, simply placing `overflow:scroll` in the style tag of the ul dd-options it works... but I cannot get the code to do that no matter what I try.

At this point its holding up my development and here I am posting for help.. I usually find the answers to my problems here so this is my first stop. help please.

Link to the plugin.
https://cdn.rawgit.com/prashantchaudhary/ddslick/master/jquery.ddslick.min.js

I am not super fluent in javascript but know enough to get by so maybe I am missing something.

Comment: as far as a dirty work around i gave my ul dd-options a id and after being generated by other code i did setTimeout(function(){document.getElementById("ddwtf").style.overflow = 'auto';},1000);

not very clean but it does the job in chrome

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. Please, edit your question and add your code and trials.